# Excel: Automatically update a graph (by one month) based on a date/value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

So I am having some trouble. I have a set of data in Excel, I have 12 months (Jan, Feb, etc) with values underneath and a graph representing the data.

I know you can use the offset function to automatically update a graph if you add new months to the data set BUT I want to show only, say, Jan, Feb in a graph and then the graph to show March based on a date/value in a cell.
See example below:

[image]

I know you can just drag the series to the next month but I was wondering if you could automate it based on looking up a date (note: I’m using Excel 2010).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you explain a little more?
If you want to show only Jan and Feb, why not just select it?
What you mean by 'show March based on date in a cell'?
What is the relation of march with Jan and Feb? do you want to always show Jan and Feb, but the end date depends on the entry data?

Comment: In the data selected for the graph you can set up a named range / function.  In the name range, you can create a function that will create a range for you based on the date entered under your highlight.  Look up those terms and it should veer you in the right direction.

Comment: I think what he is looking for is whatever he has under his highlighted cell, it should add that month into chart, e.g the current value is 1/mar/17 so the chart should include data from Mar also, if its AUG then chart should display up to August.

Comment: Thanks guys - Qadeer Ahmed - yes that is exactly what i want.

Like i said i know you can just drag to show the march data but i want the graph to update to the next month based ONLY on the date in that highlighted cell.  So someone could change the date to 1-Mar-17 and the data will automatically appear in the graph.